# MySQL collation error

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, laravel

I have the following query. It works fine if I execute it in MySQL. But when I call it from my PHP program it give me this error:

> [PDOException]
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations
> (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

This is the query:

```sql
   SELECT * FROM  tab
    WHERE Time >= UTC_TIME
    AND Time < TIME( DATE_SUB( UTC_TIMESTAMP() , INTERVAL -5 MINUTE )) 
        AND Enabled =1
    AND (
     LastTimeStamp IS NULL 
     OR DATE( LastTimeStamp ) != DATE(UTC_TIMESTAMP())
        )
    AND d = ( 
        SELECT d
        FROM  days
        WHERE DayName = ( 
        SELECT DAYNAME(UTC_TIMESTAMP())) 
         )
```

Also both the tab and the days have `latin1_sweedish_ci` collation.

Can some one help me? I am using Laravel framework for my application.

Comment: You've got at least two equality tests in there (`d = (` and `DayName = `). You should figure out which of those is causing the problem. I'm guessing it's the DayName one.

Comment: How can I fix that? All the queries run fine when I put it in my workbench ..

Comment: http://airbladesoftware.com/notes/fixing-mysql-illegal-mix-of-collations <- 15 sec. google

All you've got is a mess with your collations in the db, you should fix that, the error should go away then

Comment: I have the same issue but with nodejs and mysql2 library instead. I have one global create schema statement that sets encoding and collation. Everytime i change the db i drop the whole schema and run create script again. No other collation statement in the file. Still the same issue. Also when running just the the `select` part of  `create view view as select ...` it works just fine but when i run `select * from view` it bugs out. Also when i run it from mysql workbench everything works fine